# Change ID to DESCRIPTION in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, friendly-url

Is it possible for me to change the id on my URL to description just using .htaccess without changing my script?

On my database I have column `id` and `description`, `id=11` and `description=Strawberry Soap`

On file.php

```
$DisplayItemRowHTML .= '<a href="ItemDetails.php?id=' . $StockID . '">' . $StockImgLink . '</a>';
```

Display on URL bar: `http://localhost/url/ItemDetails.php?id=11`

and I want to change it to `http://localhost/webSHOP/ItemDetails/Strawberry-Soap`

Comment: Without changing your script? No.

Comment: Your description is stored in your database and an `.htaccess` cannot call to your database to retrieve that info. It can only translate. You could do a redirect in the `header()` but then that is not the greatest idea when trying to maintain `$_POST` values

Comment: It could get extremely tedious with many pages, but you could certainly use a [rewrite map](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/rewritemap.html)

Comment: @ceejayoz so ? I must change the script too ? I noob in .htaccess, I think I can change it just using .htaccess .

Comment: @Rasclatt so, .htaccess just translate and can't retrieve data from my database ? could you give me please some reference about it ?

Comment: @mcon I'll learn it to complete my problem, Thank's for your guide.

Comment: You can really only do the other way around where you type in `http://localhost/webSHOP/ItemDetails/Strawberry-Soap` then your `.htaccess` converts that to something like `http://localhost/?page=shop&item=Strawberry-Soap` then your php would then search your database for the description: `select * from table where description = 'strawberry-soap'`. You would probably want to put that ID in the url: `http://localhost/webSHOP/11/Strawberry-Soap` and search for the `id` instead

Comment: @Rasclatt ok I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: @Rasclatt ok I'll try your suggestion. so, I just add a description on my script like http://localhost/url/ItemDetails.php?id=11&description=Strawberry-Soap then I change display on .htaccess to http://localhost/url/ItemDetails.php/Strawberry-Soap right ?

Comment: You need to google `.htaccess rewrite` and follow those instructions